# A framework header cannot find its own header files in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks, taglib

In Xcode, suppose that there is a framework named `Foo`.  Inside the `Foo.framework/Headers` folder there are files `File1.h` and `File2.h`.  The header file `File1.h` includes `File2.h` via the following directive:

```
#include <File2.h>
```

The `Foo` framework is a re-package of a C++ library not specifically targeted for the Mac.

Now suppose I have a project that links to the `Foo` framework.  It has a file `MyFile.mm` that includes `File1.h` via the following directive:

```
#import <Foo/File1.h>
```

Now when I tried to compile `MyFile.mm`, it always fails because it can't find `File2.h`.  How can I get this to compile and run without modifying the header files of the `Foo` framework?

For the curious, the actual framework in question is a framework-packaged version of [Taglib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) taken from the [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) source tree.  The file that I tried to include was `<taglib/mp4.tag>` and compiling the `.mm` file that includes it always fail due to `mp4tag.h` is including `<tag.h>` without the `<taglib/...>` prefix in the include directive.  The error is not only in this one header files, but there are similar issues in a large number of header files and thus modifying all of these include statements is non trivial.  All of the required "missing" header files are actually present in the framework's `Header` subdirectory.

I'm trying to use Taglib in my app and although I was able to compile Taglib as a framework with header files and add it to my app, I can't seem to get the app to compile due to the issues above.

Anybody has any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a bug with the framework - it should be using the same prefixes for its `#import` statements that it expects users of the framework to use.

Comment: This framework is not Mac OS X specific and they are C/C++ sources (no Objective-C source code in the framework).

Answer (score 1):

I think that `File1.h` should say:

```
#include "File2.h"
```

Try checking the "Always Search User Paths" option in Xcode.

Comment: The "Always Search User Paths" is checked (this is the default option). File1.h is part of the open source library and its not just one file (i.e. there are many header files that includes other header files in the library the same way).

Comment: OK, at this point I'm sure that the framework is set up incorrectly.  If you can't fix it, then you'll need to add a header search path to the Headers folder of the framework.

Comment: How can I tell whether the framework is set up correctly or not?

Comment: I meant that if it's including its own headers as if they were system headers (in angle brackets), that's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to fix it:

1. Change the code to in File1.h to use '#include '.
2. In the framework project/default target/build phases, set the "copy files" phase and add both File1.h and File2.h.
3. Make sure that the "copy files" phase is before "compile" phase.

This should fix the issue, as the framework will refer to the files exactly the same way as the code that uses the framework.